# get-winevent: working with properties

Tags: powershell, get-winevent

I try to learn powershell to automate some daily tasks.

I try to figure out all fieldnames from the get-winevent function to understand what i need to do when i want to filter a result from a lot of eventid's with several conditions.

In this simple example i want all events 4625 and the events from 4624 but only if logontype is 2. The resulttable should only include the given fields (for now all fields, later on selected fields and one custom field).
Additionaly i would like to mark local logins and remotelogins in a specific column with "local" or "remote" and network-data (IP, username, hostname).

```
Get-winevent -FilterHashtable @{Path="c:\temp\test.evtx";} |
Where-Object {$_.Id -eq 4624 -and $_.properties[8].value -in 2} 
-or
{$_.Id -eq 4625}| export-csv ($EventlogTempFolder+$_.basename + ".csv") -encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation -force
```

How can i get a list of all fields? From ID to all property-fields in the message-field?

Btw.: this code did not work as expected. sorry for that.

Comment: It should be `Where-Object {($_.Id -eq 4624 -and $_.properties[8].value -in 2) -or ($_.Id -eq 4625)} | export-csv ($EventlogTempFolder+$_.basename + ".csv") -encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation -force `

If you use -or you dont seperate the two states with {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your code

```
Where-Object {$_.Id -eq 4624 -and $_.properties[8].value -in 2} 
-or
{$_.Id -eq 4625}
```

## From `Get-Help Where-Object`

```
Where-Object [-FilterScript] <ScriptBlock> [-InputObject <PSObject>] [<CommonParameters>]

...

Starting in Windows PowerShell 3.0, there are two different ways to construct a Where-Object 
command. Script block . You can use a script block to specify the property name, a comparison 
operator, and a property value. Where-Object returns all objects for which the script block 
statement is true.

For example, the following command gets processes in the Normal priority class, that is, 
processes where the value of the PriorityClass property equals Normal.

`Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.PriorityClass -eq "Normal"}`
```

## Problem

The `Where-Object` CmdLet only accepts a *single* scriptblock (the bit in the `{}` braces)

## Fix

```
Where-Object {
    ($_.Id -eq 4624 -and $_.properties[8].value -in 2)
    -or
    $_.Id -eq 4625
}
```

Comment: thank you for your code-correction @gvee. how can i get a list of all $_. Parameters, for example `$_.id` is one of them(which i found somewhere) and all the `$_.properties[8]` from the message-fields? I mean, how do i know which property is the Logontype-Field?

Comment: @PeterCore `Get-WinEvent -LogName "Windows PowerShell" | Get-Member`

Comment: @PeterCore `$_.Properties.GetEnumerator()` should also help